# Is Clash of the Titans considered on topic for Science Fiction and Fantasy?

Tags: discussion, scope

There don't seem to be any tags on SFF.SE for *Clash of the Titans*. It seems to be in the fantasy realm, but I don't want to post an off-topic question.

**Is *Clash of the Titans* considered fantasy?**

Comment: lack of tag - most likely due to it being a trash movie and no one carrying to ask a question on it before.

Comment: @Himarm Trash film sometime rise more question too. There are few on Movies &TV ( for [1981's film](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clash-of-the-titans-1981) , for [2010'sfilm](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clash-of-the-titans-2010) and for [sequel](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wrath-of-the-titans))

Comment: @Himarm, yeah, not the best movie, but I do have a question that I have wondered about for a long time.

Comment: @KyloRen - The 1981 version is awesome. The modern ones are what my father would refer to as "*watchable rubbish*".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Both versions of the film and the 2012 sequel 'Wrath of the Titans' are clearly on-topic for SFF:SE.**

They're currently untagged, not because they're off-topic, but simply because no-one has asked a question about them (yet).

---

### Setting & Conceit.

The story is a fictionalised mish-mash of Greek, Egyptian and Sumerian myths. Gods and mortals fight against gigantic monsters, dragons, demons, beasts and worm-creatures using a varied mixture of sword and sorcery items and godly magic.

---

### **Marketing**

> Leading a daring band of warriors, Perseus sets off on a perilous
>   journey deep into forbidden worlds.
>
> Battling unholy demons and fearsome beasts, he will only survive if he
>   can accept his power as a god, defy his fate and create his own destiny.
>
> Genre: **Sci-Fi/Fantasy**,  Action/Adventure
>
> <sub><sup>http://www.warnerbros.com/clash-titans-2010</sup></sub>

---

### **Cast/Crew opinion**

**Director**

> You have creatures throughout the movie being mingled with the real
>   characters. You saw Sheik Solomon, the big wooden character.  **So, this
>   is part of the world we’re creating where it’s mythology. Its not
>   history, its not fantasy, it’s an in-between.**
>
> <sub><sup>[Director Louis Leterrier On Set Interview CLASH OF THE TITANS](http://collider.com/director-louis-leterrier-on-set-interview-clash-of-the-titans/)</sup></sub>

**Director (Sequel)**

> “For me, taking Greek mythology and all that fantasy and putting it in
>   a real world that’s epic, like Gladiator, like a big Ridley Scott
>   movie, and taking all that fantasy and putting it in, grounding it,
>   making it feel real, that’s the movie that I wanted to see when I
>   walked into Clash 1 and that’s the movie that Clash 2 is gonna be.
>   That’s what I was looking for, I was looking to come in and have a
>   real, intense, visceral kick-ass experience with spectacle but
>   grounded, with great actors, and that’s what the second one will be.”
>
> <sub><sup>[Exclusive CLASH OF THE TITANS 2 Update from Director Jonathan Liebesman](http://collider.com/clash-of-the-titans-2-jonathan-liebesman/)</sup></sub>

**Lead Actor**

> **Q.** *You’re doing another big fantasy project right now with Clash of the Titans, right?*
>
> **Sam:** *We’re filming it, at the moment.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Sam Worthington Talks Terminator, Avatar, Clash of the Titans and Green Lantern](http://screencrave.com/2009-05-08/sam-worthington-talks-terminator-avatar-clash-of-the-titans-and-green-latern/)</sup></sub>

---

### Trailers

Comment: No tags for this?

Comment: @KyloRen - This is your opportunity to create one :-)

Comment: @KyloRen tags only got created when there is a need, we can't create them in advance

Comment: @AnkitSharma, valorum, Wow, did not know that. Thanks.

Comment: And who knows, if the tag gets 50 questions, you get a shiny new [taxonomist](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist) badge

Comment: @Mooz - 50 questions about Clash of the Titans? I think that's more questions than the *makers* asked.